# Using constants across the application

Tags: java, constants

I have few constant values which I refer across my application. I am creating a class something like below snippet.

```
    public class Styles {

public static final String tableStyle = "TableGrid";
public static final String fontFamily = "Calibri";
public static final String headerStyle = "Heading2";
public static final String footerStyle = "Heading3";
public static final String tableHeaderStyle = "Heading1";
public static final String tableDataFontFamily = "Cambria";
public static final int tableHeaderFontSize = 16;
public static final int tableDataFontSize = 12;

   }
```

I am assigning the values in it and I am referring them like `Styles.headerStyle` . My doubt is, is this the good way or is there any better approach to achieve this? something like `Enum` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this probably belongs to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your application, in most cases it is not a good practice to have a collection of constants in that way, but it is difficult to tell without knowing the context of your application. BTW, **are sure that you'll never (or almost never) change things like "fontFamily"**?

Of course an enum would be a little less verbose and more functional:

```
public enum Styles {

    TABLE_STYLE("TableGrid"),
    FONT_FAMILY("Calibri"),
    HEADER_STYLE("Heading2"),
    FOOTER_STYLE("Heading3"),
    TABLE_HEADER_STYLE("Heading1"),
    TABLE_DATA_FONT_FAMILY("Cambria"),
    TABLE_HEADER_FONT_SIZE("16"),
    TABLE_DATA_FONT_SIZE("12");

    private String value;

    private Styles(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can also add a property file but you can use any approach in this answer the number 16 & 12 are String

Comment: he has int xD not String

Comment: @morgano It is a stand alone java application.

Comment: @MaheshVarma it's ok, you could use either static variables or enums, but I'd use a properties file as suggested by @ nachokk, that way you'd decoupled those values from the application and it would be clearer to edit if you ever need to edit values

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use an external file as a `Property File`.

2) You can use an enum as @morgano answer

3) I would change your class declaration to

```
public final class Styles { // final class can't have childs

private Styles(){} // you cannot instanciate

public static final String tableStyle = "TableGrid";
.
.
.
}
```